# Transpose Of Matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, transpose

I am new on Python i am working on Transpose of matrix but i found it lengthy code any short procedure please!

```
mymatrix=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12)] 
for myrow in mymatrix: 
    print(myrow) 
    print("\n") 
    t_matrix = zip(*mymatrix) 
for myrow in t_matrix: 
    print(myrow)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install numpy in order to import it 
 Numpy transpose returns similar result when
 applied on 1D matrix

```
import numpy  
mymatrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] 
print(mymatrix) 
print("\n") 
print(numpy.transpose(mymatrix))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]] )
print(matrix.T)
```

---

without using numpy

---

Edit: for Both Python2 and Python3

**Python3**

```
[*zip(*matrix)]
```

**Python2**

```
zip(*matrix)
```

Comment: elegant alternative without numpy as well, bravo

Comment: As a note, this zip solution is valid just for `python2`

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip`:

```
mymatrix=[(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12)] 
myTransposedMatrix = list(zip(*mymatrix))

>>> myTransposedMatrix
[(1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11), (3, 6, 9, 12)]
```